# force facebook app to always use https

Tags: facebook, https

Is there any way to make the link to the app page use HTTPs - or another way to get the page to load facebook as a whole as https?  At present the app page just loads a blank, it has to run off of https.  I've also looked into if you can set the canvas URL to https to see if that would help - but facebook seems to set that for you.

Comment: why don't you just redirect to the https site?

Comment: the problem is that if the iframe doesn't load then i can't - unless there's a way to do it without the iframe loading

Comment: _Why_ does the iframe “not load”? Because your site accepts HTTPS requests only …? Then I’d recommend setting up a dummy page, reachable via just HTTP, that does nothing else then redirecting to the HTTPS version.

Comment: Hi - thanks.  That's a method that we are trying now

Comment: You can redirect to https with or without iframe.